# Derive value of generic from parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way for TypeScript to derive the value of a generic parameter from the type of the parameter that is passed?

Consider the following setup.

```
type Param<Result> = { bar: Result };

function foo<ResultType, ParamType extends Param<ResultType>>(
  value: ParamType
) {
  //
}

foo({ bar: "foo" });
```

I want the `ResultType` to be derived from the value passed to `foo`, in this case `string`. Since I do not explicitly set a value for the `ResultType` param, TypeScript defaults to `unknown` with

```
function foo<unknown, {
    bar: string;
}>(value: {
    bar: string;
}): void
```

while I want

```
function foo<string, {
    bar: string;
}>(value: {
    bar: string;
}): void
```

The goal is to type the return value of `foo` based on `Result`. I do not think that the approach works at all, but maybe there is another way to achieve the same result?

I am grateful for every hint!

Comment: If your goal is to just type the return type, then you could use [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND2XRW).

Comment: You should propably do this in two steps like this:```const foo = <ResultType extends any>() => (value: Param<ResultType>) => { }
const x = foo<string>()({ bar: "foo" });```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only goal is to get the return type of `foo` based on `ParamType`, you could instead say that `ParamType` is `Param<unknown>`, then using `infer` in the return type to get what is "inside":

```
type Param<Result> = { bar: Result };

function foo<ParamType extends Param<unknown>>(
  value: ParamType
): ParamType extends Param<infer U> ? U : never {
//                         ^^^^^^^ make TypeScript try to infer what's inside
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/ND2XRW)